# How to find tagged fb photos of users and friends

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to find tagged fb photos of myself and/or of my friends

When I run this FQL query (which is from the facebook docs: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo_tag/)

```
$str_fql = "SELECT pid FROM photo_tag WHERE subject=me()";
$arr_data  = $this->facebook->api( array( 'method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => $str_fql ));
var_dump($arr_data);
```

it returns an empty array. However, i do have photos that i am tagged in.

any help?

Comment: Query seems to work if you change "me" to a FB ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are getting user_photo_video_tags and/or user_photos [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/) when you authenticate.

Comment: Thanks @bkaid you are right! I never had those permissions. As well use: "friends_photo_video_tags" to get your friends tagged photos